# What is the source of these "Lay Bodhisattva Vows"?

Tags: chinese-buddhism, bodhisattva-vows

Okay, I'm well familiar with the regular Bodhisattva vows from the Brahma Net Sutra. That set of vows is open to both lay and monastic followers.

I just found another set on Dharma Realm Buddhist Young Adults and I can't figure out where they come from (which sutra).

Full text linked below. It has 6 major and 28 minor precepts. It has precepts like, 21st-- pay your taxes and 27th-- don't raise silk worms.

Is this a modern set of precepts or does it have a older origin?

ref: 
http://www.drby.net/attachments/035_The%20Bodhisattva%20Precepts%20for%20Laypeople%20-%20English.pdf

(Above PDF came from this link: http://www.drby.net/index.php/Events/Lay-Bodhisattva-Precepts-Transmission.html )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I found the answer.

It's from the "Sūtra of the Upāsaka Precepts" (Shansheng Jing). It was translated into Chinese in the 5th century.

http://www.sutrasmantras.info/sutra33c.html

This sutra has similarities to the older Sigalovada Sutta http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.31.0.ksw0.html

(Ref comparing the UPS and Sigalovada: "Buddhism and Peace", chapter 10)